# Reference a Column From Another Table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to create the following tables (simplified to the keys for example):

```sql
CREATE TABLE a (
    TestVer VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    TestID INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE b (
    RunID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    TestID INT NOT NULL
);
```

Where `TestID` is not unique, but I want table b's `TestID` to only contain values from table a's `TestID'.

I'm fairly certain I can't make it a foreign key, as the target of a foreign key has to be either a key or unique, and found that supported by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984022/postgres-fk-referencing-composite-pk).

It appears possible with Triggers according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230968/how-to-make-a-trigger-work-like-a-foreign-key) where mine on insert would look something like:

```sql
 CREATE TRIGGER id_constraint FOR b
   BEFORE INSERT
   POSITION 0
 AS BEGIN
   IF (NOT EXISTS(
      SELECT TestID
      FROM a
      WHERE TestID = NEW.TestID)) THEN
    EXCEPTION my_exception 'There is no Test with id=' ||
      NEW.TestID;
 END
```

But I would rather not use a trigger. What are other ways to do this if any?

Comment: You have to use a trigger either a system one(FK) or your own custom one.

Comment: Ok that was my suspicion, helpful to have it confirmed

Comment: Does it make sense to add a third table with `TestID` as PK.

Comment: Table 'a' is a list of all the testcases for a codebase, and there are other fields (which I didn't list) that are unique based on the TestVer.  So It's not a bad idea as then table 'b' could reference that third table with a FK,, but then the third table would have to consist of just TestID, which isn't the best format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trigger is the only way to continuously maintain such a constraint, however you can delete all unwanted rows as part of a query that uses table b:

```sql
with clean_b as (
    delete from b
    where not exists (select from a where a.TestID = b.TestID)
)
select *
from b
where ...
```

Comment: Ok, makes sense. I like this option as it quietly removes offending rows rather than throwing an exception. Thanks!